# Skrollr being triggered but not aninmating

Tags: skrollr

I'm using skrollr in a responsive website(bootstrap 3) to move a div background and fade in some images. I know skrollr is activating since it is changing the opacity of the image I am trying to fade in to 0. If I scroll the page down and resize the window the background will snap into place.

Here is the site:
http://www.healthinsurancehosting.com/dev/example/#/ceo_letter/

I am refreshing the skrollr on page load

```
s = skrollr.init({ forceHeight: false });           
s.refresh();
```

html:

```
<div class="secHead" id="secMain-3"  data-center="background-position: 50% 0;" data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% 100px;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -100px;" data-anchor-target="#secMain-3">
```

css:

```
#wrap {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: block;
z-index: 0;
}

.secMain {
display:                none;
position:               absolute;
top:                    0;
width:                  100%;
height:                 100%;
border:                 0;
margin:                 0;
padding:                0;
clear:                  both;
z-index:                10;
overflow:               hidden;

overflow-y:             scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One of the keyframes is missing a unit to match the other

before

`data-center="background-position: 50% 0;"`

after

`data-center="background-position: 50% 0px;"`

But that's not the issue. You're not scrolling the body (`overflow:hidden`), but the different sections. Skrollr only checks the scroll position of the body (scroll down a bit and execute `skrollr.get().getScrollTop()` in your console. It's always `0`)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response

Where do I set the missing keyframe? I've looked at other examples and don't see where I am missing it.

Is there any way to get around the Overflow:hidden issue on the body? If I remove that then the page functionality breaks.

Comment: You need to change to page in a way that the body scrolls.

Comment: I removed the overflow:hidden on the #wrap and body and replaced it with 

overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;

on the #wrap

The body should scroll now but no change.

Comment: Doesn't `#wrap` scroll now instead of the body?

Comment: I my mistake! 

the body now has:
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;

and it's working now. 

the background image still doesn't move but thats a keyframe issue you said.

Comment: I updated the answer. I was talking about the `data-center` one.

Comment: Everything is working great now, however some other issue has cropped up.  I am using destroy() and refresh() when each section is animated in. In firefox and IE8+ the background image starts almost half way down and then snaps up to the top of the page to its starting key frame. I'm I not defining the starting keyframes correctly?

http://www.healthinsurancehosting.com/dev/annualreport2013/#/ceo_letter/

Comment: Why are you using `destroy`? Can you explain? All you need should be a `refresh` when a new section comes in.

Comment: If I don't destroy the instance of skrollr on every section animation then the page jumps up to the top regardless of where you are in that section. It looks glitchy.

Comment: It was the key frames like you said. I fixed them and it worked nicely now. I also removed the destroy() and placed the refresh() in a more reasonable spot.

Given my current css structure, up would it be possible to pause the scroll for an animation?  I've played around with this using this example: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/examples/pausing.html

My positions are not fixed, can this be done with relative or absolute positioning?

Comment: You can't really pause scrolling, that's why the examples fakes this. You could start the animation at some point and then constantly call `setScrollTop(position)` to keep the user from scrolling while it's running.

Comment: How do I constantly call setScrollTop()?

Comment: Uhm, like `setInterval(function() {s.setScrollTop(1337)}, 33);`

Comment: This works but the page is very jumpy when you scroll. Almost like a spring.

Comment: I gave up on the pausing, its not possible with my page structure. 
Thanks for making and supporting this awesome plugin!